# arp_cache option explain

Tags: arp

```
$ ip ntable show dev eth0 
inet arp_cache 
    dev eth0 
    refcnt 4 reachable 20744 base_reachable 30000 retrans 1000 
    gc_stale 60000 delay_probe 5000 queue 31 
    app_probes 0 ucast_probes 3 mcast_probes 3 
    anycast_delay 1000 proxy_delay 800 proxy_queue 64 locktime 1000
```

Can You explain several options showing in arp_cache? I.e. refcnt, gc_stale, queue etc.

Answer (score 1):

From [Documentation for iproute by Marek Andreánsky](https://is.muni.cz/th/207915/fi_b/iproute.pdf) (page 30):

> **Refcnt** shows the number of references the NDISC cache has. Val- ues
>   above 0 prevent the NDISC cache to be prematurely freed.
>
> **Gc_stale** determines how often to check for stale ARP entries (in
>   milliseconds). After an ARP entry is stale it will be resolved again.
>
> **Queue** is the length of the ARP queue, all packets to be sent for neighbor entries in the incomplete state are collected here. The queue
>   size is in packets.